# C#/WPF: Disable Text-Wrap of RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, word-wrap

Does anyone know how I can disable the text wrapping of a `RichTextBox`?
E.g. if I have a large string which doesn't fit in the window, the `RichTextBox` places the part of the string which can't be shown of a new line. I want to disable that (and make it visible only by using the `Scrollbar`).

Thanks a lot.

Cheers

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) in WPF is simply an editor for a [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx).
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx):

> Text always wraps in a **RichTextBox**. If
>   you do not want text to wrap then set
>   the [PageWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.pagewidth.aspx) on the [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) to
>   be larger than the width of the
>   **RichTextBox**. However, once the page
>   width is reached the text still wraps.

So, while there's no way for you to explicitly disable the word-wrapping of a `RichTextBox`, you can do something like this:

```
richTextBox1.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
richTextBox1.Document.PageWidth = 1000;
```

Which will have essentially the same desired effect until you have a line that exceeds the `PageWidth`.

**Note** (as of July 2015): VS2015 RC allows `wordwrap = false` to work precisely as OP seems to desire. I believe earlier versions of Visual Studio did also.

Comment: I do not like the solution because then the horizontal Scroolbar is visible all the time...

Comment: it would be nice if you could set that upon detecting (somehow) that wrapping is needed (e.g. check each "run" [paragraph] width or something) and turn it back off when not needed (monitoring text change to check everytime, although it might be slow)

Comment: You can set `richTextBox1.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto`

Comment: `richTextBox1.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto` doesn't work

Comment: No, there is no WordWrap property for a WPF RichTextBox or FlowDocument control, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Since no answer was satisfying for me, here is my solution:

```
private void RichTxt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = new TextRange(richTxt.Document.ContentStart, richTxt.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
    FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(richTxt.FontFamily, richTxt.FontStyle, richTxt.FontWeight, richTxt.FontStretch), richTxt.FontSize, Brushes.Black);
    richTxt.Document.PageWidth = ft.Width + 12;
    richTxt.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = (richTxt.Width < ft.Width + 12) ? ScrollBarVisibility.Visible : ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
}
```

Question is about performance depending on text length and how often it is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to display a large string and tried the RichTextBox but I did not like the solution with setting the PageWidth of the Document to a fixed size. The scrollbar would be visible all the time and the scrolling area was be to big.

If a TextBlock is sufficient you can use that instead and place it inside a ScrollViewer. It worked perfect for me since I did not need all the extra features of the RichTextBox.

```
<ScrollViewer Width="200"
              Height="100"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                  <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap">
                      <TextBlock.Text>
                          Very long text Very long text Very long text 
                      </TextBlock.Text>
                  </TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: a TextBlock isn't editable, plus I don't think it supports rich formatting

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis TextBlock is not editable but it support rich formatting using nested formatting tags. Bold, Hyperlink, etc.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, except the scrolling gets a bit stuttery if you add a lot of text .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show the horizontal scrollbar, enforce a MinWidth on the ScrollViewer:

```
<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="2000" />
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>

</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

**VerticalScrollBar :**

VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="200"

**HorizontalScrollBar :**

HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxWidth="400"

Answer (score 0):

Suitable solution for me. The idea was taken from  [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/22612/wpf-auto-width-for-flowdocuments-content.html)
I defined in XAML

```
            <RichTextBox x:Name="PART_rtb" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextChanged="MyRichTextBox_OnTextChanged">
                <RichTextBox.Document>
                    <FlowDocument x:Name="PART_fd"  >
                        <FlowDocument.Resources>
                            <!--This style is used to set the margins for all paragraphs in the FlowDocument to 0.-->
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>

                            </Style>
                        </FlowDocument.Resources>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox.Document>
            </RichTextBox>
```

In Code

```
   private void MyRichTextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double i  = PART_rtb.Document.GetFormattedText().WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace + 20;
        (sender as RichTextBox).Document.PageWidth = i;
    }
```

Comment: RichTextBox.Document doesn't have a `GetFormattedText()` method 