# Text Wrapping in WPF FlowDocumentScrollViewer/RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I prevent the `text wrapping` in a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` or in a `RichTextBox`? A `Textblock` do not work:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="203,12,12,6" Grid.RowSpan="4">
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="rTB" />
</TextBlock>
```

I load a `FlowDocument` in the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` with `formated text`. I save and load the `FlowDocument` in a `Database(binary)`.
There is an example in [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor), but i dont understand it. It's to complex for me. I dont use MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the solution [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368047/c-wpf-disable-text-wrap-of-richtextbox), although there is a little problem in it (the horizontal scroolbar in RichTextBox will be visible all time).