# WPF RichTextBox word wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, word-wrap

I am trying to display a large amount of data in a WPF RichTextBox control.
My data contains space characters. There is a default word wrapping behavior that does not allow a "word", to be split and displayed on more lines.

This behavior is triggered by having space characters, questions marks, full stops or any other sentence/word delimiter. In the example below, if you replace the space character with a letter ( ex: "X" ), everything will be displayed as expected. As no delimiter characters are found, the big "word" is allowed to be truncated and displayed on multiple lines.

Is there a way of disabling this word/sentence wrapping behavior?

This is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverQuestion_TextBoxWrap.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="535">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox Name="RichTextBox" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the cs code behind:

```
 public MainWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     Random rnd = new Random();

     RichTextBox.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily( "Lucida Console" );

     Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
     for ( int i = 0 ; i < 6000 ; i++ )
     {
        Run run = new Run();
        run.Text = rnd.NextDouble().ToString() + " " ;

        par.Inlines.Add( run );
     }
     RichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add( par );
  }
```

Undesired wrapping behaviour: (please notice the different length of the lines)

```
0.562230281327958 0.269015421750497 0.130114109315963 0.527640242375266 0.592048898149305
0.73868335026255 0.478530279117883 0.939313878276997 0.890535918479104 0.00047110533363703
0.546423877378192 0.780972927241108 0.697112546626997 0.66897076306351 0.634957212319112
0.498651245375467 0.808829494662969
```

Desired wrapping behaviour: (please notice the same length of the lines)

```
0.562230281327958 0.269015421750497 0.130114109315963 0.527640242375266 0.592048898149305
0.73868335026255 0.478530279117883 0.939313878276997 0.890535918479104 0.0004711053336370
3 0.546423877378192 0.780972927241108 0.697112546626997 0.66897076306351 0.63495721231911
2 0.498651245375467 0.808829494662969
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#/WPF: Disable Text-Wrap of RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368047/c-wpf-disable-text-wrap-of-richtextbox)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to disable the word wrapping in the RichTextBox control, that is always enabled, according to the documentation in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx):

> Text always wraps in a RichTextBox. If you do not want text to wrap
>   then set the [PageWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.pagewidth.aspx) on the [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) to be larger than the width
>   of the RichTextBox. However, once the page width is reached the text
>   still wraps.

There's no explicit property to disable it, and you can do something like this:

```
richTextBox1.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
richTextBox1.Document.PageWidth = 1000;
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1369184/702048).

Comment: Hi Alberto. Thank you for the response. I have already tried this approach, but I don't want the content to be displayed on only one line. I need it to wrap on multiple lines, without trying to prevent words from splitting.

Comment: @Stefan You're welcome. One line? The PageWidth fixes only the width of the page in which the contents are displayed. Set for example PageWidth = 500, your contents won't be displayed on only one line (tried with Kaxaml).

Comment: Thanks again. I have just tried to set the PageWidth to 500. For this particular data pattern, it seems to work as all the data would fit in 2 columns. It does not work if the data pattern is different and we have more space characters. Also, this solution does not work when trying to resize the window. I would expect the contents to auto-resize, without having a fixed size. I don't want to get rid of the wrapping behavior completely, I just need a way of making it not depend on sentence/word separators (space, full stop, question mark, etc characters), as shown in the original question.