# WPF RichTextBox horizontal scroll not working

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, scrollview, richtextbox

In my wpf application , i am using a richtextbox. Its vertical scrollbar is working fine. But its horizontal scrollbar is not working.

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

It is not giving proper results. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your text box is wrapping the inner contents which is a default for the RichTextBox Control. If you wish to explicitly enable it being scroll-able, you can do something similar to [this StackOverflow Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368047/c-wpf-disable-text-wrap-of-richtextbox).

Comment: All long lines that exceed the width of RichTextBox have been auto-line breaked, and no horizontal scroll bar appears.

Answer (score 0):

**VerticalScrollBar :**
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="200"

**HorizontalScrollBar :**
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxWidth="400"

Answer (score -1):

WPF Property of ScrollBar property can be changed by

```
richtextbox.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
```